# Running Selenium RC tests in firefox in offline mode

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, offline-mode

Is there a way to run Selenium test in offline mode?  If I set the offline mode in the firefox profile, selenium is stuck at selenium.start().  I'm using the python client driver.  The code is as below

```
sel = selenium('localhost', 4444, '*firefox', 'file:///home/user/selenium/selenium-python/client-driver-1.0.1/inputs/input.html')
sel.start()
sel.open('file:///home/user/selenium/selenium-python/client-driver-1.0.1/inputs/input.html')
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What is your goal?

Comment: This was what I was trying to achieve.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160416/run-a-javascript-file-on-a-set-of-html-documents

I got it working with pyqt and webkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following description in a [blog](http://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/creating-firefox-profile-for-your-selenium-rc-tests/) helped me to fix the same problem, but using selenium with java junit tests.

Without knowing to much about running selenium from python, I do not see where you are starting the selenium RC server with the firefox profile.

i.e

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate “”
```