# run javascript on multiple html files

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a folder with 1000 html files.

I have to remove certain nodes using xpath from each html. SO i have made the javascript. I cant open each file and run the javascript through firefox console.

I m using linux, so how to do

Comment: It's probably best to use a Python/Ruby library to render the HTML files and inject the JavaScript. My best guess is to use Selenium.

Comment: i dont want to inject the script. i want to apply the script and remove some content.

Comment: You seem to fail to understand what injecting means. It just explains that Selenium will add JavaScript after each page-rendering (it's an automated web browser). After injecting the JavaScript you could store the newly processed DOM in a separated folder or just overwrite the current files. Selenium gives you all that power.

Comment: ok is it available in linux.

Comment: Of course; http://www.seleniumhq.org. Could you maybe share an example so we can better understand what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can be run on a Linux server using [nodejs](http://nodejs.org).

Here are the javascript APIs for accessing the file system in nodejs.

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

You will also need an xpath library for nodejs.  There appear to be several.
https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/xpath

Nodejs is sometimes confusing to a newcomer because while it is single threaded it is also designed to be asynchronous, asking for a callback function to call when the information is available and returning immediately. Many of the file system calls have a "sync" in the name.  These are "synchronous" and might be more suitable if your automatic editing application is mostly already written in a synchronous style.

Comment: i will go through it.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be easier to do with any server side language.

You can make a PHP file which reads the directory where your 1000 HTML files are, loads them one by one changes them, and saves them.

For example:

```
if ($handle = opendir('projects')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
      $file = file_get_contents($entry);
      $file = // make your changes here
      file_put_contents($entry, $file);
    }
  }
  closedir($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help to go through node.js solution:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6kD6BNW4GE

Comment: but using nodejs can i call a file and run dom related tasks and same the file