# Selenium with Firefox Offline Mode

Tags: firefox, selenium

I am trying to make selenium (web automation test framework) work with firefox in offline mode.

I found this here, which mentions starting selenium with a firefox profile.

[Running Selenium RC tests in firefox in offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155140/running-selenium-rc-tests-in-firefox-in-offline-mode)

This is exactly what I am after, but the part I am missing is how to make a firefox profile start in offline mode?

The reason I am wanting to do this is I am using the new HTML5 functionality to allow my application to run offline.

Alternative can this kind of thing be done with Watin?

Answer (score 0):

## Solutions

## 1

Just create and refer to your profile and block your internet connection

## 2

Maybe this is also helpful:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/work-offline/

Or simulate the keypress for Data -> Offline Mode in the Firefox menu

## 3

Or set the `network.online` > false

in the firefox profile (about:config)

Comment: Hi, the network.manage-offline-status > true option doesn't seem to do what you think. I was looking at that yesterday and it just seems to control whether firefox will go into offline mode when the network is unplugged. It doesn't force it into offline mode.

Comment: It's bizarre because I tried that one also and I am pretty sure that isn't it either. Perhaps there is good documentation around for the about:Config items?

Comment: I found this, so perhaps you are right. I will give it another look, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Networking_Preferences

Comment: network.online>false seem to do nothing. Firefox still access internet.

Answer (score 0):

A bit ugly, but working workaround is to set a non existing proxy in profile. Code:

```
String surelyNotExistingProxyAddress="192.168.100.100:7777";
org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy(surelyNotExistingProxyAddress)
     .setFtpProxy(surelyNotExistingProxyAddress)
     .setSslProxy(surelyNotExistingProxyAddress);
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
```

Then this firefox will load surely nothing from the internet.