# Can only online application is tested by selenium?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, desktop-application

I want to know that only online website or web application is tested by selenium.?
What I can do for offline or desktop application?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'online'.

Comment: Online means web based and on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is only for web-based automation really.

There are plenty of [tools for GUI testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools) though.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can only automate certain web browsers. So, I guess no for desktop applications. Also, people do use selenium with [firefox offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386813/selenium-with-firefox-offline-mode?lq=1).